# custom AutoClose vim plugin

Tags: vim, auto-close

I am using the AutoClose plugin for vim and I was trying to add my own custom feature which will close my `<%` with `%>` but right now when it is closing my  cursor is being placed in the middle of the `%` and `>` therefore I have to go back with the arrow keys. Does anyone know how to fix this? Right now I have this line in the `autoclose.vim` file:

```
let s:charsToClose = {"<% ": " %>", "<%= ": " %>"}
```

I am using the AutoClose plugin by Thiago Alves found here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2009

Comment: Which autoclose? There are several and some have identical names.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2009

Comment: I think that it's hardcoded to go 1 char to the left (see line 75) but you'd need to go 2 characters to the left. You could add an if-else to see if the replacement pair's right member is made of 2 chars or 1.

Comment: @romainl I tried messing around with this file by could not get it to move two lines back, do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit rough but it works here.

After adding your pairs to

```
let s:charsToClose = {'(': ')', '{': '}', '[': ']', '"': '"', "'": "'","<% ": " %>", "<%= ": " %>"}
```

Change line 75 from:

```
let l:result .= s:charsToClose[a:char] . "\<Left>"
```

to:

```
if len(a:char) > 1
    let l:result .= s:charsToClose[a:char] . "\<Left>\<Left>\<left>"
else
    let l:result .= s:charsToClose[a:char] . "\<Left>"
endif
```

Comment: Maybe to `let l:result.=s:charsToClose[a:char].repeat("\<Left>", len(split(a:char, '\v.@=')))`?

Comment: BTW, [latest development version](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose) does not have `s:charsToClose` variable at all and script page of referenced script describes `g:AutoClosePairs`. Plugin does have another error when using `g:AutoClosePairs` with same contents though.